# Autodesk Revit Architecture 2014 .NET API C# find room bounding elements in link

Tags: c#, revit-api

I've Revit 2014 over here. I know that the walls in linked documents can be marked as room bounding. An yes, that works great. However, from the API I cannot find the which walls from those linked documents are room bounding for my Room.
I can find which linked documents serve as bounds to my room, but not which walls in those linked documents are used.
Is there any way of finding this?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at some of the RayTrace features of the API to make this work best, but here's a little piece of code that'll probably prove a big key:

```
            Room rm = new Room();
            SpatialElementBoundaryOptions sebo = new SpatialElementBoundaryOptions();
            var boundaryitems = rm.GetBoundarySegments(sebo);
```